# R: quit !incomplete.cases() function without loosing workspace

Tags: r, function, process

I started the `!incomplete.cases()` function to identify missing data and made a typing-error. So I wanted to restart it, but it doesn´t stop. I´ve tried `quit(save="default", status = 0, runlast = TRUE)` but that doesn´t work either. No reaction. Any ideas how I can stop the function without losing the script/data saved in the workspace?

Comment: `incomplete.cases()` is not a base R function. From what package is this function found?

Comment: @Elisa: `incomplete.cases` is not in the VIM reference manual...

Comment: It does not appear to be in the VIM package. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VIM/VIM.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must mean this dialog:

```
Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
> 
Selection:
```

It's not a nice thing to see. It means that R has crashed. You choose one of those items by typing a number between 1 and 4 and then "return". I got it after starting a vmGUImenu() session and apparently clicking in the wrong place (trying to close a X11 graphics window after the X11 dialog box stopped responding to clicks.) I think this X11 GUI may not be "mature" on the Mac platform.

Comment: Ahh, okay. By now it has entirely crashed, I think pressing the Esc was too much. Thank you. Next time I´ll know what to do.

Comment: @Elisa: It gave a message on the console that suggested it was expecting a click in one of hte diagonal panels of the graphic, but that message was hidden by the graphic. Generally `esc` is not fatal if the r script is well behaved. I would try to cycle through your open windows next time.

Comment: +1 For fixing the mind-reading engine.

Answer (score 1):

It's platform-dependent.  Press "Esc" in Windows and "Ctrl-C" just about anywhere else.

Comment: Or try `Ctrl+Break` in Windows if `Esc` doesn't work.

Comment: Ctrl-C seems to stop the script of the function ('Selection:  ') but it keeps running and it does not allow me to type anything new. also there is no '>'.

Comment: @Elisa: I don't follow.  It stops the script, but what keeps running?  Yes, "Ctrl-C" is what to use on a Mac.

Comment: it only stops the 'Selection' skript the function itself keeps showing, however I can tell that it is still running (little scroller on a mac) and it also doen´t show the '>' indicating that it is waiting for a task...

Comment: @Elisa: I don't know what a "Selection" script is.  You may need to issue the command more than once, and you may have to wait awhile for it to stop (e.g. if your machine is using swap space).

Comment: 'Selection:' is a script that is part of the !incomplete.cases() function. When you start the function it keeps showing that command. So I take it there is no other way to stop a command before it is done without closing the workspace, e.g. when I typed in something wrong and it is taking too long?

Comment: @Elisa: I'm not familiar with the `incomplete.cases` function and you haven't told us where to find it.  It could be that it calls compiled code that runs a long loop and never checks for user interrupt, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. it´s a command from the VIM Packages. I guess  I will just have to close the workspace. Thanks for the help!